# Persisting dynamic variables across tests

Tags: javascript, cypress

I need to persist variables set in one Cypress test through to subsequent tests. This doesn't seem possible using global variables or by setting env variables with Cypress.env. If a value is set in test1, the scope is lost in test2 and the value will be null.

// test.spec.js

```
describe("Login to site", () => {

let _magicCode

context('Signup', () => {
    it("Should go through the signup flow", function () {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('xDevUrl') + '/create-account')
        cy.get(MAGIC_CODE_FIELD)
            .invoke('val')
            .then(magicCode => {
                   Cypress.env('magicCode', magicCode)
                   _magicCode = Cypress.env('magicCode')

                   cy.log(Cypress.env('magicCode'))

                   //result: 12345

                   cy.log(_magicCode)

                   //result: 12345
            })
    })

    it("persist magicCode value please", function () {
        cy.log(Cypress.env('magicCode'))

        //result: null

        cy.log(_magicCode)

        //result: null
      })
   })
})
```

// Cypress.json

```
{
"baseUrl": "https://site1.test.dev/",
  "env": {
   "magicCode": ""
    }
 }
```

I would expect the value of magicCode to be persisted across tests, since it is a global variable that is assigned within a .then() block.  Why is the value being lost, and how can it be persisted?

Comment: Cannot repro. What's your Cypress version?

Comment: v4.3.1 (latest)